# Endless loading huge php file with high memory_limit

Tags: php, memory-limit

## Intro

Currently I am working with XML files. With PHP I combine several XML files. This is a big operation that exceeds the default memory_limit of PHP.

When I extend the limit with `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` the fatal error is gone and the script doesn't exceed the limit anymore.

The problem I have now is that after combining the XML files my script is buggy.
Browsers are loading endless, I am still able to do everything serverside. Like e-mail myself, adding rows to the database. But everything clientside just dont work. Like a simple `echo 'Hello World';` or `header('location: http://www.google.com');`

While combining the files I log the steps.

```
$stores = $this->Store->getAll();
$this->log(2, 'all', 1337, 'Start processing ' . count($stores) . ' stores ';
foreach($stores as $store)
{
    $this->log(2, $store->id, 1337, 'Start processing store ';
    $this->process_store($store->id, false);
}
$this->log(2, 'all', 1337, 'Done with processing ' . count($stores) . ' stores ';
header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/datatest');
die();
```

The strange part is that my script DOES log the last log `Done with processing`. Anything I do at serverside works.

But the header (redirect) just doesn't. My browser is just endless loading.

## Questions

- What is going wrong?
- Do browsers disable communication with the server after some time?

Comment: @Chris Technical my script wont execute the `die()` or `exit()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the server and client disconnect from each others.

Finaly I found the solution, which is realy ugly!

I had to set a `sleep(1);` inside the foreach loop to keep the server and client connected.

Omg this is slower then before :'(

Comment: Mmm minimum working `usleep(30000);` So 3x faster :) Thanks @EricCope

Answer (score 0):

You could circumvent the memory problem by doing a recursive XML merge using simpleXML

**Code**

```
<?php
private function mergeXML(&$base, $add)
{
    $new = $base->addChild($add->getName());
    foreach ($add->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        $new[$a] = $b;
    }
    foreach ($add->children() as $child) {
        $this->mergeXML($new, $child);
    }
}?>
```

**Usage**

```
<?php mergeXML($xmlElement, simplexml_load_string($toMerge)) ?>
```

So you would start out and merge XML 1 with XML2 to TempXML1, then merge TempXML1 with XML3, etc. This way, you just go down the list of xml files without loading all of them into memory.

Comment: XML merging/combining is working correct. Files are ok. Saves to database works after loop. Even e-mailing myself works after loop. But at client side, the browser keeps loading. Nothing else :(

Comment: Well if that is so, maybe client side is requesting multiple merges which cram the memory. You should check on that.

Comment: I dont know what you exactly mean. In the logs I also save `memory_get_peak_usage(true)/1024` and the last log tells me `102656`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that BASE_URL . '/datatest' is a correct URL?
You should also put a capital L to Location to ensure the redirect works properly.

Try this without the entire merging to verify that your header redirection works at first.

Comment: Im totaly sure that the header works. Used it more. My browser is just endless loading...

Comment: Could you try with your exact line but without the merging and ensure you are redirected?
As I said, you should have Location and not location for it to work

Comment: I tried, both location and Location work. (In real code I use `$this->redirect();`)

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to be sure. Are you sure nothing is printed by your script? no error/warning displayed preventing the header to work ?

Check you error logs. You could use ob_start()/ob_end_clean() to ensure nothing is printed and check if it changes anything?

Comment: That's pretty strange... How long does your script run before the header?

You could try to just "sleep" for this time and then just redirect and check if it works in this case. If it works then there's an issue in the way you merge, something your did not see. If not there's an issue in the header not working after a long time.

Comment: Can you also post your code with ob_start() ? Because if you have for example a new line at the end of an included file (after ?>) or a space before <?php this could lead to the header() not working and you having the impression that nothing is printed.

Comment: The problem is not my redirection. Also just a simple `echo 'Hello World!';` doesn't work. My browser keeps loading.

Comment: Can you do a OB_flush at the end? Does it laod quickly if you take out the header redirection?